# Does Apple's Open Source License permit static linking of a library?

Tags: license, open-source

I have a closed-source project that I'm thinking of linking against one of Apple's open source libs, modified. As I understand it, I should publish my derived work under the same license stating the changes made.

But can I link it against my project statically, or is it limited to dynamic linking only?

Answer (score 1):

According to APSL you are allowed to modify and use their library for profit uses as long as you A)Leave the apple copyright code intact and B)you include the modified code. You don't have to make your entire project open-source but the modified library does have to be open-source. Hope this helps!